# How to parse an attributed XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

Friend,
I'm totally exhausted by looking to parse a remote XML file have attribute values, I have used DOM method to parse, here is the XML structure

```
<horoscopo fecha="2014-04-06 00:00:00.000">
<zodiaco signo="Aries">
<prediccion tipo="texto">
Tienes la sensación de que alguien intenta traicionarte. No te dejes sorprender y enfréntate el primero a este tipo de situaciones
</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="amor">3</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="salud">3</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="trabajo">1</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="dinero">2</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="numero_suerte">10</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="pclave"/>
</zodiaco>
<zodiaco signo="Tauro">
<prediccion tipo="texto">
En el día de hoy te verás sorprendido por la reacción de alguien de tu entorno. No te esperabas tal reacción de parte de esta persona.
</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="amor">2</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="salud">4</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="trabajo">5</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="dinero">3</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="numero_suerte">30</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="pclave"/>
</zodiaco>
<zodiaco signo="Géminis">
<prediccion tipo="texto">
No estás mirando en la buena dirección. Afortunadamente uno de tus familiares estará presente para guiarte. Confia en él sin duda.
</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="amor">2</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="salud">3</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="trabajo">5</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="dinero">1</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="numero_suerte">9</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="pclave"/>
</zodiaco>
<zodiaco signo="Cáncer">
<prediccion tipo="texto">
Hoy, tienes que escuchar tu intuición. Una pequeña voz en tu fuero interno te ayuda para dirigirte y guiarte, ¡no escuches a nadie más!
</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="amor">5</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="salud">4</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="trabajo">4</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="dinero">2</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="numero_suerte">43</prediccion>
<prediccion tipo="pclave"/>
</zodiaco>
</horoscopo>
```

I need the node values depends on user select the zodiac, for example, when user select the zodiac "Aries" I need only its child nodes values only. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You can parse  using xmlpullparser. How you checked that in the docs??

Comment: can you give me some example? Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. example is there in the docs.